# It is better to call a Room DataBase query many times or create a variable?

Tags: java, android, android-room

It is something that may seem very new but I have this doubt, I will do it with a simple example:

I have a database with a table that contains, among many other things, a "name" column

When I want to use the name of id 1 many times, what is the best practice?

Option 1: Create a String variable called "name" to make a single query in the database
Option 2: Call "name" directly from the database every time it is to be used

I always create a variable to avoid many queries in my database but I don't know if I'm right

```
String name = appDataBase.tableDao().getName(id);
    textView1.setText(name);
    textView2.setText("Employee: " + name);
    .
    .
    .
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. If you are not modifying the value, it is preferred to `Create a String variable called "name" to make a single query in the database`
2. If you are modifying it , it is preferred to `Call "name" directly from the database every time it is to be used`
3. If somebody else can modify the name, and you need to see the latest value, `Get it from the database directly`

Comment: 3. if somebody else can modify the name, and you need to see the latest value, get it from the database directly.

Comment: thanks. I will add it

Answer (score 1):

CRUD operations are always "expensive". Usually they involve network call. Avoid as.muchbas possible. Less is better.